# How to add three colors of texts in a single span without using a <font> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

how to add three colors of texts in a single span (details-red, Enter-blue, here-yellow) without using a `<font>` tag. Is that possible?

```
<span>Details Enter Here</span>
```

Comment: Font tag was deprecated.!

Comment: Just either have 3 spans or 3 other tags inside the span with classnames

Comment: any other method with out using font tag,span?

Comment: What you are asking is not possible

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without using 3 separate tags of some sort since you need an identifier or something to add the color to. Just plain text isn't enough of a specifier. Here is an example showing how to use it with either 3 separate `<span>` or 3 separate `<div>`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/c3GKW/)

Comment: iam not looking this type. iam trying only in single span

Comment: @kannan sorry but, as far as I'm aware, that is not possible. Why do you need it to be one single span? It won't affect performance

Comment: sir, we have a common css  so we cant use the font tag, including more span will need to change other pages also

Comment: @kannan You can do it either directly in the tag(like in my example). That way, you wont even have to touch the css

Comment: i given directly in tags but first it fetchs the common css

Comment: @kannan CSS will use the most specific identifier (which for some reason isn't allways what is given in `style="..."`). You can either try adding `!important` after the property (like `style="color:red!important;"` or you can add and ID to the span and change it in the markups `<style>`-tags. That way, you wont have to alter the master.css file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 3 different span in order to do that as shown below:

```
<span style="color:red">Details</span>
<span style="color:blue"> Enter</span>
<span style="color:yellow"> Here</span>
```

Comment: iam not looking this type. iam trying only in single span

Answer (score 0):

While there is no CSS selector for words, you can't do it without any additional tags inside the `span`. As `font` tag is deprecated, you still might be able to use other inline tag. The most common is `span`, so there is no problem wrapping a span inside a span, as it is allowed (valid for HTML 4 and 5) to wrap inline elements inside a `span`.

You said in a comment above:

> sir, we have a common css so we cant use the font tag, including more span will need to change other pages also

So this is right, if you split the `span` tag into three tags. But you should be able to wrap some additional `span` inside the existing tag, like:

```
<span>
    <span>Details </span>
    <span>Enter </span>
    <span>Here!</span>
</span>
```

Then you might be able to use classes for the child `span` or even use some CSS magic like:

```
span:first-child {
  color: red;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}
span:last-child {
  color: yellow;
}
```

This way, there is no need to change any of the current CSS (so other pages won't be affected), but you might need to add some additional selectors for the new tags (you might even do this inline like `<span style="color: blue">` if you don't want to touch the CSS files).

You can [try the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6V4N7/1/). Hope this helps!