# I want to color a special character in text not all text

Tags: html, css

First Name *
                    enter your first name

```
            <p>
                <label>Last Name *</label>
                <label>enter your last name</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "lastName" />
            </p>
```

I want to color * as red without adding additional tag with it. I want this rule throughout document.

I want just like it.
Lasst Name *(with red color)

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add three colors of texts in a single span without using a <font> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113190/how-to-add-three-colors-of-texts-in-a-single-span-without-using-a-font-tag)

Answer (score 3):

You can use pseudo elements `after` or `before`.

```
.lastName:after
{
  content: '*';
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: +1. Ofcourse `before` can be used with some adjustment to positions, but for this specific case I would prefer using `after` (like in your example) just because the mark comes after the label.

Comment: Have in mind that this inserted character won't be a part of the DOM literally but a part of the pseudo class ::after (for example you won't be able to select it)

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, this cannot be done with straight up CSS without changing the DOM, or the content of the first label.

One alternative would be to remove the asterisk `*` from the `label` then in your CSS do, e.g:

```
p label:first-child:after{
  content:'*';
  color:red;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9NF3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no way to do this without changing the DOM.

That being said, you don't necessarily have to add the tag when you create your html. So if the reason you don't want to change the html is that you do not control it, you can do what you need to do after the fact with javascript/jQuery.